# Ubuntu not recognizing full RAID disk on Dell Poweredge R720

Tags: server, filesystem, disk-usage

On installation the system only gives me the ability to install on a 3.5tb section of my hard drives. However the system is configured with 3625gb of storage.

When typing `sudo fdisk -l` it responds as follows:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 63.28 MiB, 66355200 bytes, 129600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 111.95 MiB, 117387264 bytes, 229272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 49.84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 3.54 TiB, 3892716765184 bytes, 7602962432 sectors
Disk model: PERC H310
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F438DFC9-465B-4921-8257-AA8BD9AB76AB

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    2203647    2201600    1G EFI System
/dev/sda2  2203648    6397951    4194304    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  6397952 7602960383 7596562432  3.5T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 3.54 TiB, 3889436819456 bytes, 7596556288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Here is the information from `sudo lshw -class storage -class disk` where the full storage capacity can be seen.

```
  *-raid
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon]
       vendor: Broadcom / LSI
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: scsi0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: raid pm pciexpress vpd msi msix bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=megaraid_sas latency=0
       resources: irq:43 ioport:fc00(size=256) memory:ddffc000-ddffffff memory:ddf80000-ddfbffff memory:dd000000-dd01ffff
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          product: PERC H310
          vendor: DELL
          physical id: 2.0.0
          bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: 2.12
          serial: 00e4d14e161bed072c005776c6e03f08
          size: 3625GiB (3892GB)
          capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
          configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=f438dfc9-465b-4921-8257-aa8bd9ab76ab logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

I not sure why the system is not recognizing the full 3892GB of storage, and am not entirely sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated
Im not too experienced with this operating system, so apologies for any errors in formatting, im willing to give additional info to anyone willing to help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the usual marketing "trick".

To sell the vendors use base 10^3 divisor (1000), while computers work with base 2^10 divisor (1024):

Computer:

```
3892716765184/1024/1024/1024/1024
3.54
3892716765184/1024/1024/1024
3625.37
```

Marketing:

```
3892716765184/1000/1000/1000/1000
3.89
3892716765184/1000/1000/1000
3892.71
```

You see the bytes shown by `fdisk` are exactly the size shown by the `lshw`, just different conversion.